# How to get the date of a post in WordPress, so I could use it in a script?

Tags: posts, date-time

I'm very new to WordPress. I need to get the date of a post and compare that date to a specific date (04/01/2011), so add some banners and stuff to every post created "after" that pivot date. But the only functions I found in the wordpress documentation are examples of functions to "print" the date, like the_time(), etc.

Anyone knows how I could made this thing?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 4):

[get_the_date](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_date) and/or [get_the_time](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_time) will return the date/time of the post rather than printing it.

Comment: Some sample would be appresiated...

Comment: @Nathan The function names in my answer are links to the WordPress codex pages for these functions. Those pages include the sample/default code on their use.

Answer (score 1):

just use the following code

```
<?php echo the_time(get_option('date_format'));?>
```

to get the time in any of wordpress page
if you want to get the date then use just the following code

```
<?php echo the_date(get_option('date_format'));?>
```

i think that code solve the problem. :)